# How to change currency in stripe API PHP code?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I want to change currency from USD to EURO, but it's not working.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_CZZ6uxdf53acUM9IwJBqA1OF');

$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
'card' => $_POST['stripeToken'],
'amount' => 6.53, 
'currency' => 'EUR',
"description" => ""
));
```

[See attachment which shows USD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhoVz.png)

Comment: that attachment is for Stripe checkout you'd specify data-currency="eur" in the script tag in the html

Comment: The screenshot seems to be showing a Stripe.js instance. Can you recheck again?

Comment: it works, Thank you so much Matthew, you save me, Thank you again

Comment: i updated my html code with new attribute which you gave me, it works man